# Unable to change the license from Customer Community Plus to Customer Community

Tags: community, customer-community, trailhead

Previously I gave this user the Customer Community Plus License but when I tried to change it to Customer Community, it throws an error. It will be really helpful if I get a solution.

[image]

I am just learning community, in fact this is a trailhead problem. So please excuse if I made any silly mistakes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to switch the license from Customer Community Plus to Customer Community as it would result on loss in functionality on some objects and tasks.  An administrator must disable the contact as a Customer User and then re-enable as a Customer User to create a new user record and associate it with the new license.

Check [Communities Licenses Eligible for Upgrades](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_license_upgrade_eligible.htm&type=5)

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Vinay, firstly thank you for the explanation. Can you suggest me like what should I do for this trail: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/community_rollout_impl/community_rollout_impl_sharing?trail_id=communities&trailmix_creator_id=mechthild&trailmix_slug=community-cloud-certification

I have made the sharing set and enabled Community from Communities Settings and all. But while checking the challenge I got this problem: The "Customer Community User" for the contact "Edna Frank" is not created properly.